# Sort list string according to another list string

Tags: java

I have a `List<String>` with values like so:

```
static String input = "pro or 7";
List<String> arrayOfString = Arrays.asList(input.toLowerCase().split("\\s+"));
```

I have another list of string :

```
static List<String> organizations = Arrays.asList(
        "Service Provider organisation 3 01254 25742", // count=3
        "Service Provider test 2 132455 132455",       // count=1
        "Service Provider organisation 2 78900 6521",  // count=3
        "VOYAGES ANSELMINO 30876168300025 382510022",  // count=1
        "Service Provider test 1 32722 21211",         // count=2
        "SP recherche autocomplete 7897788 7897788")   // count=1
        .stream().map(String::toLowerCase)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I want to sort the list organizations according to the elements of the list arrayOfString

Example:

- str = Service Provider test 1 32722 21211

`count` will be equal to 2 because `str` contains 'pro' and '7'

- str = SP recherche autocomplete 7897788 7897788

`count` will be equal to 1 because `str` contains '7' (eliminate duplicate characters)

Then sort the list organizations according to the result of `count`

Comment: did you try and fail? show what you tried please.

Comment: Seems like an assignment question, so I would refrain to give you complete solution. Just a hint: Use stream.sorted method with a custom comparator. `.stream().sorted(new Comparator() { ... } )`

Comment: "For Mother" doesn't contain "pro", and it doesn't contain "7", but it _does_ contain "or". So what would `count` be: zero or 1?

Comment: @KevinAnderson count be: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implement it according to the hint{@Lokesh give} as an exercise.
You can refer to it.

```
List<String> organizations = Arrays.asList(
    "Service Provider organisation 3 01254 25742", // count=3
    "Service Provider test 2 132455 132455",       // count=1
    "Service Provider organisation 2 78900 6521",  // count=3
    "VOYAGES ANSELMINO 30876168300025 382510022",  // count=1
    "Service Provider test 1 32722 21211",         // count=2
    "SP recherche autocomplete 7897788 7897788")   // count=1
    .stream().map(String::toLowerCase).sorted(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return getCountMeetCondition(o2) - getCountMeetCondition(o1);
        }
}).collect(Collectors.toList());

private static int getCountMeetCondition(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfString.size(); i++) {
        if (s.contains(arrayOfString.get(i))) {
            count++;
        }
   }
   return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final Function<String, Set<String>> split = str -> new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str.toLowerCase().split("\\s+")));
final Set<String> keys = split.apply("pro or 7");
final Function<String, Integer> getCount = str -> {
    int count = 0;
    str = str.toLowerCase();

    for (String key : keys)
        if (str.contains(key))
            count++;

    return count;
};

final Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(getCount::apply);
```

You can use this `comparator` to sort your collection.